# Mongo php Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad geo query'

Tags: php, mongodb, geospatial

I'm trying to build a query to search geospatial data in mongo using php-mongo library.

Object structure

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("536ecef59bdc8977f1e9c06f"),
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                -74.220408,
                40.727703
            ]
        ]
    },
    "bounds" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                [
                    -74.221403,
                    40.728457
                ],
                [
                    -74.219413,
                    40.728457
                ],
                [
                    -74.219413,
                    40.726949
                ],
                [
                    -74.221403,
                    40.726949
                ],
                [
                    -74.221403,
                    40.728457
                ]
            ]
        ]
    },
    "tile" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                [
                    -74.220498,
                    40.727772
                ],
                [
                    -74.220318,
                    40.727772
                ],
                [
                    -74.220318,
                    40.727634
                ],
                [
                    -74.220498,
                    40.727634
                ],
                [
                    -74.220498,
                    40.727772
                ]
            ]
        ]
    },
    "status" : "2",
    "dev" : "0"
}
```

Indexes

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "atlantic.Analyzer_Marks"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "location.coordinates" : "2d"
        },
        "name" : "location.coordinates_2d",
        "ns" : "atlantic.Analyzer_Marks"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "bounds" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "bounds_2dsphere",
        "ns" : "atlantic.Analyzer_Marks",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "tile" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "tile_2dsphere",
        "ns" : "atlantic.Analyzer_Marks",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
    }
]


    $mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://someserver.com:27017");
    $marks = $mongo->selectDB('atlantic');
        $q = array('bounds' => array(
          '$geoWithin' => array(
              '$geometry' => array(
                  'type' => 'Polygon',
            'coordinates' => array(array(
                    array(40.125246,-74.327963),
                    array(40.125246,-74.325989),
                    array(40.123738,-74.325989),
                    array(40.123738,-74.327963),
                    array(40.125246,-74.327963)
            ))
              )
          )
       )
    );
$marks = new MongoCollection($marks,'Analyzer_Marks');
    $marks = $marks->find($q);
    //var_dump($marks);
    $results = array();
    if(!empty($marks)){

        foreach($marks as $mark) {
            $results[] = array(
                "location" => $mark['location'],
                "tile" => $mark['tile'],
                "status" => $mark['status']
            );
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with
>   message 'someserver.com:27017: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad
>   geo query' in /var/www/html/one-call/lib/somefile.php:97

MongoDB Version 2.6.1

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce that error. I think you are missing one more array call wrapping around the array of coordinates:

```
    $mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://someserver.com:27017");
    $marks = $mongo->selectDB('atlantic');
    $q = array('bounds' => array(
           '$geoWithin' => array(
             '$geometry' => array(
               'type' => 'Polygon',
                 'coordinates' => array(
                   array(
                     array(40.125246,-74.327963),
                     array(40.125246,-74.325989),
                     array(40.123738,-74.325989),
                     array(40.123738,-74.327963),
                     array(40.125246,-74.327963)
                   )
                 )
              )
          )
       )
    );
```

after modifying the code I don't receive that error anymore

Comment: I originally that that was the issue to, but I tried it and got the same error as before. I'll update the code to reflect this.

Comment: Can you share any more data on example document schema and data plus indexes? As it is that code runs fine on 2.6 for me, no errors.